# Download video from Youtube: errorcode=150

Tags: video, youtube, download

I'm writing a script for download videos from youtube. I know, I need to parse file with video info downloaded from url: http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={video id}. And it works fine, but some videos are "protected" from embedding on external websites (and I dont want to EMBED video, I want to DOWNLOAD it). And for example:

for this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgqOSCgc8xc I can't retrieve any video info from this url:
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=cgqOSCgc8xc, only these parameters (below), with errorcode 150:

> cosver=6.1&csi_page_type=embed&cos=Windows&status=fail&cbr=Chrome&**errorcode=150**&enablecsi=1&errordetail=0&cbrver=38.0.2125.111&c=WEB&eventid=XftVVJbEA-nziwaU2YGgBw&reason=Ten+film+wideo+zawiera+tre%C5%9B%C4%87+od+partnera+WMG.+Mo%C5%BCliwo%C5%9B%C4%87+jej+odtwarzania+w+okre%C5%9Blonych+witrynach+jest+zablokowana.%3Cbr%2F%3E%3Cu%3E%3Ca+href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DcgqOSCgc8xc%26feature%3Dplayer_embedded%27+target%3D%27_blank%27%3EObejrzyj+w+YouTube%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fu%3E

But I saw, that others scripts for downloading youtube videos doesn't have any problems with this.
So, how can I get exact file with video info?

Answer (score 2):

When the request for the video info "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=cgqOSCgc8xc" is sent off to YouTube, YouTube expects that the request is arriving from a site that is attempting to embed a player and play the video.

There are some videos that YouTube will not allow you to play from a player that is embedded in a website (except YouTube itself). The owners of those videos are usually the ones that choose not to allow the embedding to happen. So your current approach will not work as YouTube will deny your request for video info every single time.

So...you need to make a different "request" from YouTube for the video info. It's difficult to help you not knowing what language/script/API you're using for your download, however I was able to use a strategy to get the raw video URL using iOS/Swift language.

Regardless what API you use, the strategy is the following:

1) Use a web browser interface provided by the platform used in order to launch and play the video in question.
2) If the video is playing then it's safe to conclude that your used platform was able to send a URL request to get the video stream URL and play it.
3) Figure out what API exists on your platform that will allow you to see what the above mentioned URL request is.
4) Use the URL request to download the video. Keep in mind that the URL has an expiry so don't bother caching it.

Comment: I'm developing on iOS/Swift and have the same issue. Can you share your workaround of the problem?